# For $H$ the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, prove $|AH|h_a+|BH|h_b+|CH|h_c=\frac12\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)$

Tags: geometry

> Given acute $\triangle ABC$ with orthocenter $H$, prove $$|AH|\,h_a+|BH|\,h_b+|CH|\,h_c=\frac12\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)$$

I tried to do something with the perimeter, area, half-perimeter, but I can't solve it. I am not good at contest problems, and I just started practicing. I'll be glad if I get an answer or just guidelines. I couldn't seem to find this problem solved or guidelines for it anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What work have you done so far?

Comment: Please define all objects that appear, starting with the triangle and $ha$ (which may be some $h_a$, typed as `h_a` in LaTeX), in the text, **not (only)** in the title. Then please show the own efforts to solve. Else there are some people that downvote from the start.

Comment: If you don't want your question to get downvoted, you should include more context such as your own attempt at a solution. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26017/is-it-a-rule-of-math-stack-exchange-that-when-asking-a-question-its-never

Comment: What are $h_a$, $h_b$, $h_c$? Are they the lengths of the altitudes from $A$, $B$, $C$?

Comment: I believe so. It wasn't specified in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A',B',C'$ are feet of the altitudes, from $ABA'\sim AHC'$ we have $AH\cdot h_a= AB\cdot  AC'$. Similarly, from $BAB'\sim BHC'$, $BH\cdot h_b= AB\cdot  BC'$ follows. By adding we have $AH\cdot h_a+BH\cdot h_b=AB(AC'+BC')= AB^2=c^2$. By symmetry, $BH\cdot h_b+CH\cdot h_c= a^2$ and $AH\cdot h_a+CH\cdot h_c= b^2$. Now just add these three equations.